# How to remove the label with the street name from street view in Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the JavaScript Google Maps API to display a map in street view mode.
I disabled all the controls with `disableDefaultUI: true` but it still displays a label with the street name placed in the middle of the street road.
How can I hide that label?

Comment: Could you please give us a sample of your implementation?